# Hidden @Font-face ? font-weight 700 resorts to local Arial instead of custom font

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I can't seem to use the custom font I want on my server nor on my gulp browsersync demo.

For an h4 element, I have the @font-face rules in place in chrome, I can see it.

I have Raleway-Regular.woff2 for font-weight 700 and Raleway-Black.woff2 for font-weight: 900

If you put this you can see the same.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

.h4,
.h5,
.h6 {
  font-family: "Raleway", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700; /* changing to 800 works for Raleway */
  line-height: 1.1;
  color: inherit;
}
```

For some reason using localhost or remotely, when I inspect element on an H4, look at "computed" tab. You can see rendered font: Arial.

If I modify font-weight of h4 to "900", then it goes to Raleway-Black. If I change it to 800 it goes to "Raleway-Bold". But if I go to "700" suddenly, it doesn't render Raleway-Regular.woff2... it goes back to "Arial".

**Why is Arial being displayed instead of Raleway-Regular.woff2 ?**

In my code I am using Bootstrap & gulp with wiredep etc. But I do not see any font-face anywhere in my html being rendered other than Font-Awesome and Glyphicons. Which work fine.

I only have one custom CSS for bootstrap. I have disabled any other bootstrap plugins.

Sass is available too, but my sass file being rendered has no "font-face" or "import".

Comment: Syntax looks right to me, so this is pretty mysterious, but on a "using proper CSS syntax" note, don't quote font-family values unless the value contains spaces or special characters. This is just a single word, so it's just `Raleway`, not `"Raleway"`. That won't fix your problem, but it's worth knowing and practicing.

Comment: Good to know. I still couldn't figure it out, but there are many things to try still. I am guessing something could be cached or some fonts are loaded to replace it based on font-weight: 700 and lower. Font-weight:800++ works fine.

Comment: have you tried a private browser window (which *should* bypass cache), or with dev tools open and the setting "disable cache when dev tools are open" checked?